# SQL select all non-unique rows that have at least one specific value in another column

Tags: mysql

Thanks for viewing. I am having a hard time figuring out the SQL call that will identify all complete orders with at least one instance of a value 'Red' in the Color column. Again, I want it to include all rows for the order that meets the criteria. Thanks!

---

```
Order    Color
1        Red
1        Blue
1        Yellow
2        Red
2        Black
3        Blue
3        Green
3        Pink
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, for instance you could use the `in` predicate:

```
select * 
from your_table
where `Order` in (
    select `Order` 
    from your_table 
    where Color = 'Red'
)
```

or you could use the `exists` predicate with a correlated query:

```
select * 
from your_table t1
where exists (
    select 1 
    from your_table t2 
    where t2.Color = 'Red' 
      and t1.`Order` = t2.`Order`
    )
```

Both queries would return:

```
Order   Color
1       Red
1       Blue
1       Yellow
2       Red
2       Black
```

On a side note `order` is a reserved keyword in the ANSI SQL standard and as such isn't a good name for a column.